# Removing Duplicates in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

How to automatically remove duplicates in access base on some criteria.

Suppose I have 10 fields, and removing duplicates when two or more fields have same entry repeated.

Comment: Is this something you just need to do once? or is this a user process you are trying to setup?  There is a query wizard to find duplicates, you can use those results to base your delete query on.

Comment: this is a user process, i need to do whenever i append data from two different sources. I am able to find duplicates by query wizard i need to delete those duplicated automatically, say from delete duplicate data from second source. There are lot many duplicates so dont want to do manually

Comment: what have you got so far? what attempts have you made?  What errors are you getting?  Have you tried creating the query to find your duplicates, then using that query to delete your duplicate records?  you should be able to accomplish this thru standard predefined queries or through VBA.